# Web sites see my firefox as a mobile browser

Tags: firefox

Something strange happening to me is that some sites see firefox as a mobile browser on ubuntu and force usage of their mobile interface with no option to switch to full view. They work well with chrome on ubuntu and firfox on windows.

So how can i solve this problem ?

**Update:**

- Example site:

  http://www.shorouknews.com (It's an Arabic news website)
- My user agent string:

  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101027 Ubuntu/10.10 (maverick) Firefox/3.6.12

Please note that the site works well on Chrome in ubuntu and Firfox on windows.

Comment: Can you give one as an example?

Comment: And can you tell us what your "user agent string" is reported as? You can see it here: http://whatsmyuseragent.com/ Edit your question to add both bits of information.

Comment: I added an example site and user agent string to the question.

Comment: perhaps a screenshot might rectify problem to us..

Comment: Same problem here... quite annoying!

Comment: On a side note, you are using an old version of Firefox and probably other applications as well. You nee to update your system using the Update Manager. It won't fix your problem, but will make sure you have the latest security patches. In regard to your problem, you could try Firefox 5. See Firefox 4,5 & Beyond Mega Thread: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1712247

Answer (score 4):

That particular site does the same for me in default Firefox on Ubuntu 10.10.

The problem is with particular websites, not with Ubuntu. It's possible they are somehow deciding you are probably using Android or something similar.

I'd suggest contacting the website owner.

Alternatively you could install the [user agent switcher Firefox add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/59/) to pretend you are using a different browser/operating system and fool the website.